# Decrypting a ZIP file in PHP encrypted using Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes, sha256

I've been trying to decrypt a ZIP file in PHP which was encrypted using Java.
I already have written a function in Java, which is decrypting files perfectly. However, I haven't been able to decrypt the file in PHP.
Please find the code snippet below. Please let me know if more info is required or I'm unclear anywhere.

**Java (Decryption Function)**

```
final SecretKeySpec aeskeySpec = this.generateKeySpec(salt);
final Cipher AESCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
AESCipher.init(2, aeskeySpec);
final CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(encryptedFile), AESCipher);
final FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
this.copy(is, os);
```

**Java (generateKeySpec)**

```
private SecretKeySpec generateKeySpec(final String text) throws SecurityException {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = null;
        try {
            byte[] key = ("xxxxxxx" + text).getBytes("UTF-8");
            final MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, this.AES_KEY_SIZE / 8);
            secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex2) {
            final Exception ex;
            final Exception e = ex;
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
        return secretKeySpec;
}
```

**PHP Code I've written so far**

```
if (file_exists('file.zip')) {
    $file = file_get_contents('file.zip');
    $key = unpack('C*', 'xxxxxxxxx');
    $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($file,'AES-256-CBC', hash('sha256', 'xxxxxxxxx'));
    $newFile = fopen('decrypted.zip', 'w+');
    fwrite($newFile, $decryptedData);
}
```

Any sort of help is most appreciated.

Thank you all! :)

Comment: First error `AES` in Java means `AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding` not AES-CBC as you have used in php. BTW: The modern password based ZIP encryption would have been more secure than this self-developed encyrption as it uses ECB which is known to be insecure. Therefore my suggestion: throw it away and use the existing AES based ZIP encryption using a good password.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the input, I will definitely look into the method you've mentioned. However, I can't really change anything in those Java Functions right now, as they're already in production. 

If you could give me a bit more info on what MessageDigest.digest() method does, and where to look for IV, it will definitely help me move to the right direction.

Comment: IV is only used by CBC mode. As the Java part uses ECB there is no IV. `MessageDigest.digest()` in yozr case simply calculates the SHA-256 on the input data in `key`.

Comment: As a general point, different systems use different defaults, and any mismatch will cause an error.  You are better off explicitly setting everything on both sides so you can be sure that they match.